# How to get background conversation in a sound record?

Tags: noise-reduction

I have a audio file which belongs to a security camera that recorded inside of a cabin. There is a conversation taking place outside of the cabin and I need to get that conversation. Is there a way to do that? Removing background noise via Audacity didn't help much so far.

Comment: have you read the top few posts in the Related sidebar to the right?

Comment: Could you add a short example of the audio?

Comment: @RoryAlsop I did read a few related threads about this problem, but I couldn't find anything useful. Most of them focuses on removing background voice, not foreground.

Comment: @n00dles I believe the actual voice record is not useful for your inspection, because it's not in English, it's in Turkish, so you probably can not decide if the voice is cleared enough or not.

Comment: I can't see why you wouldn't find a useful answer elsewhere on this site, therefore there must be something different about your recording. If you want better answers, you should post an audio file. iZotope RX is one of the best audio repair tools anyway, if you want a simple answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use [RX 5 Audio Editor](https://www.izotope.com/en/products/audio-repair/rx/).

You will probably get better results than with Audacity.

RX 5 allows you to recover certain parts that are missing.

Many quality presets are provided and you'll also find exhaustive documentation on the net.

Comment: Some information regarding why this application will provide better results would be helpful.

Comment: it has a lot of preset menus, I'm discovering...

Comment: Do you like it?